# Navigator.push().then not calling a Function

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my students list screen, which has an add student button and upon taping save on the form it pops back to the students list.

```dart
class _StudentListState extends State<StudentList> {
  var students = new List<Student>();

  _getStudents() {
    APIServices.fetchStudents().then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response);
        students = list.map((model) => Student.fromJson(model)).toList();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();  
    _getStudents();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton:_buidFloatingButton(),
      appBar: _buildAppBar(context),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
// ================== REFRESH BUTTON ============================
        child: FlatButton(
          child:Icon(Icons.refresh),
          onPressed: () {
            _getStudents();
          },
        ),
// =======================================================
      ),
// ================== ADD STUDENT BUTTON =======================
  Widget _buidFloatingButton() {
    return FloatingActionButton(
        child:Icon(Icons.person_add),
        onPressed: () {

            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddStudent())).then((value) {
              _getStudents();
            });

        },
      );
  } 
// =======================================================
  }
}
```

I'm trying to refresh the student list after the form pop with this code, as seen in above code:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddStudent())).then((value) => () {
  _getStudents();
});
```

[image]
[image]

It's not refreshing the student list, but it will refresh if I tap the refresh button, both attempts are executing the same _getStudentes() function.

At the end of the save button I just do a:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: could you try returning a value from Navigator.push method like value = await navigator.push... then in your pop method use Navigator.pop(context, value); after that setState((){  students = value}) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **returning a function** with `(value) => () { ... }`.

The shorthand syntax in JavaScript and Dart differs a little in that regard, let me explain:

```dart
// Expression that returns a function.
() {
  ...
}
// You could also assign it to a variable:
final foo = () { return 3; };
// Now, you can call foo:
final bar = foo();
```

Thus, you are returning a function with `(value) => () { ... }`.

What you want to do instead is either of the following:

```dart
(value) => _getStudents()
// or
(value) {
  _getStudents();
}
```

[Learn more about functions in Dart](https://dart.dev/samples#functions).

Comment: I added to my original post to make it more complete.

Comment: Correction from my last comment: at frist save it does nothing, at second save it refreshes to the previews added student, not showing the last added one.

Comment: @RaulMarquez Did you apply my change?